# How to use Percona Toolkit in a Docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, percona

I'm using Windows 10 and running MySQL 5.7.26 on this machine.

I download the docker image perconalab/percona-toolkit 3.2.0 from https://hub.docker.com/r/perconalab/percona-toolkit .

I try to run the container with the command as below.

```
docker container run --name PerconaToolkit -it perconalab/percona-toolkit /bin/bash
```

I can ping my machine from the container. But I cannot call pt-mysql-summary, it says "Cannot execute mysql".

```
pt-mysql-summary --host=192.168.16.6 --port=3306 --user=root --all-databases --ask-pass
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to run percona toolkit command to access to the remote MySQL from a docker container?

Thank you very much.

Regards,

Kevin

Comment: could you share output of `which mysql`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `percona/percona-toolkit` no longer has this problem.

Example with `docker-compose.yml`, similar to what I added myself:

```
  database-toolkit:
    container_name: database-toolkit
    image: percona/percona-toolkit
    restart: no
    profiles: ["diagnostics-only"]
    user: root
    volumes:
      - /path/to/db/files/:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      - ./conf/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf:ro
    networks:
      - database
```

And then invoking it:

`docker compose run --rm database-toolkit pt-mysql-summary --password xyz`

*Note: not recommended to put the password in the command.*